# FilePicker - clicking outside box loses all uploads

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

While using a web app, if a user happens to click out side of the filepicker box when filepicker in inside a modal, said user will loose all the uploads that were taking place.

I am wondering if there is a way to prevent this from happening. Such as disabling the binding  that closes filepicker and the modal when the modal background is clicked.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: filepickers JavaScript SDK. Web application is using rails.

Comment: Hmm. We don't have that ability yet, though it makes sense. I'll take a look at turning off the click binding when uploading.

Comment: I completely understand why that binding is in place. I feel it makes sense. I think a good approach might be to provide the user with a warning when they click on the x and/or the background while an upload is taking place. A warning similar to the ones provided by twitter bootstrap at the top of the filepicker modal that displays a warning message and two buttons. A button for dismissing the current upload and modal, and one for continuing the upload.

Just my thoughts. Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to follow up and let you know that this has now been resolved and is on by default! Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: This isn't the case for me. I just started testing Filepicker.io today and when I click on the half-opacity screen the modal closes and the upload quits.

Is this an option that I'm missing and is also missing from the docs?

Comment: It should look something like: http://cl.ly/image/0d3G1G101l3u and it is on for everyone, no configuration needed.